# Cannot run executable in eshell

Tags: eshell

I have an executable (guix) in directory under home. I am using eshell. I add that directory to PATH. But when I run the command, the executable is not found. I have tried various methods such as addpath etc. But eshell doesnt seem to search in that directory and find the executable. If I give the full directory on the command line, it works.

See below:

$ /home/rlemmon/.guix-profile/bin/guix  works correctly
$ guix does not work

$ echo $PATH 
$ /home/rlemmon/.guix-profile/bin:/home/rlemmon/bin:/ ...
$ addpath
/home/rlemmon/.guix-profile/bin/
/home/rlemmon/bin/
...

Comment: I would suggest evaluating `(getenv "PATH")` and then examine the output.  If your desired path is not included, then I would suggest evaluating `(setenv "PATH" (concat "/home/rlemmon/.guix-profile/bin:" (getenv "PATH")))` -- note the trailing `:` that is concatenated in the example ...  Then try calling your `guix` executable and see if it works as expected.  Eshell uses the `process-environment` variable, which contains (in part) the PATH.  You can also use, `C-h v` aka `M-x describe-variable` to examine the `process-environment`.  It is a local-variable in the eshell buffer.

Comment: If, for whatever the reason, you do not wish to modify the PATH component of the buffer-local `process-environment` (normally global, but eshell makes it local), then you may wish to instead work with the variable `eshell-command-aliases-list` -- again, type `C-h v` aka `M-x describe-variable` to read the doc-string.  The doc-string recommends to use the `alias` command to populate the `eshell-aliases-file`; e.g., `alias git /absolute/path/to/my/bin/git $*`